# Replace any string ending with %

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm running MYSQL v.5.6 with Phpmyadmin 4.7.3 and one of my site has been hacked and I would like to remove injected text in my articles (post_content).

The pattern is as follows :

```
<script type="text/javascript">SOME NASTY CODE</script>
<p id="alreadyXXXX"> SOME NASTY TEXT </p>
<p><script type="text/javascript">SOME NASTY CODE</script></p>
```

where X signs show random numbers

I have tried hundreds of different syntaxes like

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, '<script%>%</script>', '' );
```

or

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE ( post_content, '<p id="already%>%</p>', '' );
```

but I can't figure out what should be the exact syntax

I would like to remove all these nasty elements from my articles (script and p). Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there are no other script tags in your data except these two?

Comment: yes absolutely, there are only two scripts and one p